# build bottom toolbar in HTML and display it on IPHONE

Tags: android, iphone, html, css

when I build bottom toolbar in HTML I use the following code:
    .bottomMenu
    {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0px;
        width: 100%;

```
}

.bottomMenu div
{
    text-align: center;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

the problem is that it work just fine in ordinary browser but it does'nt work in mobile browser such as iphone or android.
how to solve this problem?

thanks in advance.

Kobi

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed positioning, which isn't really supported by iOS<5 and Android<3: http://caniuse.com/#search=fixed

Search for 'position fixed iOS' or something like that for lot's of alternative solutions :)